# Rails can't save to the database with proper date format

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've added the snippet below to my config/locales/en.yml file:

```
en:
  date:
    formats:
      default: '%m/%d/%Y'
```

Whenever I POST/PUT JSON to the server & my Rails API that includes a date, I send it in this format: `10/20/2015` which is m/d/Y.

I'm using MySQL as my RDBMS, and it stores it as `2015-10-20` which is `Y-m-d`.

I've tried running `Date.strptime(value, '%m/%d/%Y')` in my Rails controller(s) prior to Rails committing the data, but I continually get `invalid date` errors.

When I send it as 10/12/2015, or 10/10/2015 it goes in.  It's interpreting it as d/m/Y and thus works when the middle number is less than 13.

What's the solution to this?

Edit:

In my controller, I have this method to convert the date:

```
def contract_party_params
    if params[:contract_party][:birthdate]
        params[:contract_party][:birthdate] = Date.strptime(params[:contract_party][:birthdate], '%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    end

    params.require(:contract_party).permit(:birthdate)
end
```

Edit:

Rails Server output

```
Parameters: {"contract_party"=>{"birthdate"=>"10/20/1990"}}

1990-10-20
ArgumentError (invalid date):
  app/controllers/contract_parties_controller.rb:60:in `strptime'
  app/controllers/contract_parties_controller.rb:60:in `contract_party_params'
  app/controllers/contract_parties_controller.rb:23:in `create'
```

Controller Method:

```
def create
    @contract_party = ContractParty.new(contract_party_params)

    if @contract_party.save
        render :json => @contract_party, 
                     :status => :created, 
                     :location => @contract_party
    else
        render json: @contract_party.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
end
```

Comment: please post your contract party model and schema files

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work,

Try it in **Rails Console**.

```
Time.strptime("1990-10-20", "%Y-%m-%d").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

#Output

"1990-10-20"
```

In controller try this.

```
def create
  contract_party_params[:birthdate] = Time.strptime(contract_party_params[:birthdate], "%m/%d/%Y").strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

  @contract_party = ContractParty.new(contract_party_params)

  if @contract_party.save
    render json: @contract_party, status: :created, location: @contract_party
  else
    render json: @contract_party.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end


private
def contract_party_params
  params.require(:contract_party).permit(:birthdate)
end
```

Here is the link of **Strftime** http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone/strftime

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79347/discussion-on-answer-by-amit-sharma-rails-cant-save-to-the-database-with-proper).